# What naming convention should be used for tags about Arkham Horror and Eldritch Horror expansions?

Tags: discussion, tags

As the [Arkham Horror tag wiki](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/arkham-horror/info) and [Eldritch Horror tag wiki](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/eldritch-horror/info) shows, there are two naming conventions that are currently being used for expansion tags*:

**Early Arkham Horror expansions do not have a prefix**

- Curse of the Dark Pharaoh [curse-of-the-dark-pharaoh](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curse-of-the-dark-pharaoh)

  - Note that [ah-curse-of-the-dark-pharaoh](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ah-curse-of-the-dark-pharaoh) is longer than the allowed 25 characters
- Dunwich Horror [dunwich-horror](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dunwich-horror)
- Kingsport Horror [kingsport-horror](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingsport-horror)

**Later Arkham Horror expansions have an "ah-" prefix**

- The King in Yellow [ah-king-in-yellow](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ah-king-in-yellow)
- Innsmouth Horror [ah-innsmouth-horror](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ah-innsmouth-horror)
- Miskatonic Horror [ah-miskatonic-horror](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ah-miskatonic-horror)

**Eldritch Horror expansions do not have a prefix**

- Mountains of Madness [mountains-of-madness](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountains-of-madness)
- Forsaken Lore [forsaken-lore](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forsaken-lore)
- Under the Pyramids [under-the-pyramids](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/under-the-pyramids)
- Strange Remnants [strange-remnants](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strange-remnants)

What should be the naming convention of these Arkham Horror expansions going forward? And when we reach a consensus, could a mod or high-rep user please migrate tag wikis?

<sub>* The Black Goat of the Woods and The Lurker at the Threshold do not currently have tags on this site.</sub>

Comment: `ah-curse-dark-pharaoh` we could always shorten it. It'll still come up as people type it so it shouldn't be too bad to find right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably should have the ah- prefix, since as far as I can tell all other games that are an expansion for (or related to) another game have the games name (or abbreviation) as a prefix. Examples: [dominion-seaside](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dominion-seaside), [catan-seafarers](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catan-seafarers), and [mtg-commander](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-commander)

I didn't find any other games that don't fit this pattern (but it is possible I missed something from a game I don't know much about)

Comment: The proper names for the expansions you mentioned are [Dominion: Seaside](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/51811/dominion-seaside) and [Catan: Seafarers](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/325/catan-seafarers). I'll be honest, I was surprised to look up Dunwich Horror on BGG and find that that the full title is actually [Arkham Horror: Dunwich Horror Expansion](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/21059/arkham-horror-dunwich-horror-expansion). So this would be a fair reason to prefix with `ah-`.

Comment: A counter-example are the Eldritch Horror expansion tags, such as [tag:forsaken-lore]. I've gone ahead and added them to the question because they are a related situation for Arkham Horror.

Comment: Another counter-example: the [Battlestar Galactica expansion tags](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/battlestar-galactica/info). There was [a meta discussion](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/385/problem-with-expansion-tag) about how [battlestar-galactica-pegasus] was too long. We would have a problem with [ah-curse-of-the-dark-pharaoh] being too long too.

Comment: I suppose [ah-cotdp] could work.