# Expanding tags to 35 characters

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

In the past, we've had a number of tags that have been limited by the site's 25 character tag limit. Thanks to that [limit being increased to 35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/191265), we can now fix a number of these tags.

Mods have the ability to rename tags, and create tag synonyms to the old tags if necessary. So to ease their workload, we'll put this all in one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summary:

- assorted games renamed to full names (from [this answer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1699/409))
- Arkham Horror and Eldritch Horror prefixes added to all expansion tags (from [this answer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1705/409))
- [mtg-thg](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-thg) renamed to [mtg-two-headed-giant](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-two-headed-giant) (from [this answer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1710/409))

All of them have synonyms created as well, so no new questions should appear with the old tags.

For the suggestions about changing the mtg- prefix in [this answer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1700/409), I've done nothing. I don't think it's likely that people will ever need the synonyms - if they did, we would be seeing questions mistagged as [magic-the-gathering-foo](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-foo)) but we can create them as needed.

Comment: If we have more renames, do you want for us to create a new answer on this question or create a separate question?

Comment: Separate questions, so folks will see them. Mods get extra notifications for all meta questions, so it's really handy. For one-off trivial things (e.g. renaming a single tag from a shortened name to the full name of a game) you can also just custom flag a question that has that tag.

Comment: Hooray! Thank you for carrying out this work.

Answer (score 7):

## Tags that don't need much discussion

### This is a community wiki answer and can be modified by anyone

If a tag or tag group needs more discussion, it can be brought up in a separate answer.

- [agricola-fotm](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agricola-fotm) → [agricola-farmers-of-the-moor](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agricola-farmers-of-the-moor) (28)
- [betrayal-at-house-on-hill](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betrayal-at-house-on-hill) → [betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill) (29)
- [catan-traders-barbarians](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catan-traders-barbarians) → [catan-traders-and-barbarians](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catan-traders-and-barbarians) (28)
- [dc-comics-db-crisis](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics-db-crisis) → [dc-comics-deckbuilding-crisis](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics-deckbuilding-crisis) (29)
- [expansion-adrift](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expansion-adrift) → [the-captain-is-dead-adrift](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-captain-is-dead-adrift) (26)
- [imperial-assault](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imperial-assault) → [star-wars-imperial-assault](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-imperial-assault) (26)
- [lord-of-the-rings-lcg](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings-lcg) → [the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg) (26)
- [oregon-trail](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oregon-trail) → [the-oregon-trail-card-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-oregon-trail-card-game) (26)
- [pandemic-state-of-emerg](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandemic-state-of-emerg) → [pandemic-state-of-emergency](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandemic-state-of-emergency) (27)
- [penny-arcade-gamersvsevil](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/penny-arcade-gamersvsevil) → [penny-arcade-gamers-vs-evil](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/penny-arcade-gamers-vs-evil) (27)
- [sentinels-multiverse](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentinels-multiverse) → [sentinels-of-the-multiverse](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentinels-of-the-multiverse) (27)
- [t2r-alvin-and-dexter](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t2r-alvin-and-dexter) → [ticket-to-ride-alvin-and-dexter](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ticket-to-ride-alvin-and-dexter) (31)
- [witcher-adventure-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/witcher-adventure-game) → [the-witcher-adventure-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-adventure-game) (26)

Comment: I will take care of all of these, since there's been no concerns raised.

Comment: Okay, all done. Let me know if anything doesn't look right (though there's some amount of caching so if you find weird inconsistencies just wait a few minutes).

Answer (score 4):

## Arkham Horror/Eldritch Horror tags

Previously, there was a meta discussion asking [What naming convention should be used for tags about Arkham Horror and Eldritch Horror expansions?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1490/3389). The result was that we decided that the games ought to have Arkham Horror or Eldritch Horror as a prefix, just like Catan, Dominion, Magic, and other games.

However, this was never actually performed, likely due to the 25 character limit being too restrictive to already long titles and the fact that even Stack Exchange acknowledges that [the synonym suggestion system is completely ineffective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204244/191265).

Now would be a good time to get these renamed, which is more helpful with the greater character limit.

### Arkham Horror

- [ah-innsmouth-horror](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ah-innsmouth-horror) → [arkham-horror-innsmouth-horror](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arkham-horror-innsmouth-horror) (30)
- [ah-king-in-yellow](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ah-king-in-yellow) → [arkham-horror-the-king-in-yellow](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arkham-horror-the-king-in-yellow) (32)
- [ah-miskatonic-horror](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ah-miskatonic-horror) → [arkham-horror-miskatonic-horror](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arkham-horror-miskatonic-horror) (31)
- [curse-of-the-dark-pharaoh](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curse-of-the-dark-pharaoh) → [arkham-horror-curse-of-dark-pharaoh](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arkham-horror-curse-of-dark-pharaoh) (35)

  - [arkham-horror-curse-of-the-dark-pharaoh](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arkham-horror-curse-of-the-dark-pharaoh) is too long at 39 characters
- [dunwich-horror](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dunwich-horror) → [arkham-horror-dunwich-horror](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arkham-horror-dunwich-horror) (28)
- [kingsport-horror](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingsport-horror) → [arkham-horror-kingsport-horror](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arkham-horror-kingsport-horror) (30)

### Eldritch Horror

- [mountains-of-madness](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountains-of-madness) → [eldritch-horror-mountains-madness](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eldritch-horror-mountains-madness) (33)

  - [eldritch-horror-mountains-of-madness](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eldritch-horror-mountains-of-madness) is too long at 36 characters
- [forsaken-lore](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forsaken-lore) → [eldritch-horror-forsaken-lore](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eldritch-horror-forsaken-lore) (29)
- [under-the-pyramids](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/under-the-pyramids) → [eldritch-horror-under-the-pyramids](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eldritch-horror-under-the-pyramids) (34)
- [strange-remnants](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strange-remnants) → [eldritch-horror-strange-remnants](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eldritch-horror-strange-remnants) (32)
- [signs-of-carcosa](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signs-of-carcosa) → [eldritch-horror-signs-of-carcosa](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eldritch-horror-signs-of-carcosa) (32)
- [the-dreamlands](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-dreamlands) → [eldritch-horror-the-dreamlands](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eldritch-horror-the-dreamlands) (30)
- [cities-in-ruin](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cities-in-ruin) → [eldritch-horror-cities-in-ruin](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eldritch-horror-cities-in-ruin) (30)

(As an aside, because the current tags lack an `eldritch-horror-` prefix, I had to look up the expansion names on another site to see if our site even had any tags for this game!)

Comment: These are done too, same deal as the general no-discussion post.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[mtg-thg](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-thg) should be renamed to [mtg-two-headed-giant](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-two-headed-giant). In fact that's only 20 characters, so it could've been that way all along!

This was part of Thunderforge's original MTG suggestions. Ikegami pointed out it was a good idea, and I agree, so I don't want it to get lost. :)

Comment: Done, thanks for separating it.

Comment: Thanks for that!! :)

Answer (score -4):

## Magic the Gathering tags

I figured that Magic the Gathering tags should be discussed separately. We have a number of tags that are `mtg-*`. Should we expand these as well, leaving the old ones as synonyms?

- [mtg-archenemy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-archenemy) → [magic-the-gathering-archenemy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-archenemy) (29)
- [mtg-color-identity](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-color-identity) → [magic-the-gathering-color-identity](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-color-identity) (34)
- [mtg-commander](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-commander) → [magic-the-gathering-commander](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-commander) (29)
- [mtg-competitive-rel](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-competitive-rel) → [magic-the-gathering-competitive-rel](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-competitive-rel) (35)
- [mtg-cube](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-cube) → [magic-the-gathering-cube](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-cube) (24)
- [mtg-drafting](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-drafting) → [magic-the-gathering-drafting](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-drafting) (28)
- [mtg-emblems](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-emblems) → [magic-the-gathering-emblems](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-emblems) (27)
- [mtg-frontier](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-frontier) → [magic-the-gathering-frontier](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-frontier) (28)
- [mtg-history](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-history) → [magic-the-gathering-history](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-history) (27)
- [mtg-homebrew](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-homebrew) → [magic-the-gathering-homebrew](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-homebrew) (28)
- [mtg-joke-cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-joke-cards) → [magic-the-gathering-joke-cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-joke-cards) (30)
- [mtg-manabase](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-manabase) → [magic-the-gathering-manabase](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-manabase) (28)
- [mtg-modern](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-modern) → [magic-the-gathering-modern](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-modern) (26)
- [mtg-multiplayer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-multiplayer) → [magic-the-gathering-multiplayer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-multiplayer) (31)
- [mtg-online](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-online) → [magic-the-gathering-online](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-online) (26)
- [mtg-regular-rel](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-regular-rel) → [magic-the-gathering-regular-rel](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-regular-rel) (31)

Unfortunately, there are a few that are still too long.

- [mtg-commander-damage](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-commander-damage) → [magic-the-gathering-commander-damage](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-commander-damage) (36)
- [mtg-double-faced-cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-double-faced-cards) → [magic-the-gathering-double-faced-cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-double-faced-cards) (38)
- [mtg-thg](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-thg) → [mtg-two-headed-giant](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-two-headed-giant) (20) → [magic-the-gathering-two-headed-giant](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-two-headed-giant) (36)

Comment: Despite the capacity to rename many of these, I'd personally prefer to keep the shorter "mtg-" prefix. Otherwise more than 50% of the tag is prefix "noise", i.e., not the important bit! SEO tends to do just fine with search engines understanding "mtg" = "magic the gathering".

Comment: Yeah, I think if we wanted a name that wasn't a slightly informal abbreviation, I'd prefer "magic" rather than "mtg". Wizards refers to it as Magic all the time; I don't really see us needing to spell it out.

Comment: I agree the prefix should be either mtg or magic, magic-the-gathering is far too long. I don't really have a preference either was as to which it is.

Comment: We could always do both (or all three), with the longer name as a synonym pointing to the shorter name. I think that would be useful, so that this list shows up when you type "magic" into the question tag box.

Comment: I like the synonym idea, and second the motion to use "mtg" as the prefix for the synonym target, e.g. [magic-the-gathering-modern] points to [mtg-modern].

Comment: I agree that the "mtg" prefix is probably best.

Comment: The suggestion to expand [tag:mtg-thg] to [tag:mtg-two-headed-giant] is a good one, though.